# javascript how do i get .data info within a function with forEach function?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

playing around with foreach fuction atm, and trying to get .data out of it.

```
const foreachfunc = (data = null) => {
    data.forEach((element, index) => {
        console.log('element = ' + element, 'index = ' + index)
        let head = element.head
        console.log(head)
    });
};

const myarray = ["test1", "test2"]

foreachfunc(myarray)
```

okay so right now it outputs:

```
element = test1 index = 0
undefined
element = test2 index = 1
undefined
```

and it does makes sense since i haven't giving 'head' any data yet. But is it possible to give 'head' data within 'myarray'?

Comment: Yes. That is called Array of Objects `[{ head: "head", text: "test1"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your array as it does not contain data that you are trying to access. check updated code below

```
const foreachfunc = (data = null) => {
    data.forEach((element, index) => {
        console.log('element = ' + element.text, 'index = ' + index)
        let head = element.head
        console.log(head)
    });
};

const myarray = [{head:"head1",text:"text1"},{head:"head2",text:"text2"}]

foreachfunc(myarray)
```